# Report Viewer .rdlc How to pass a parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

So apparently I been doing a trial balance report in C# windows form - report viewer that shows a YEARLY report of "ACCOUNTS" and its total payable in each account.

The report has a supposed yearly compounding value depending from the user choice -
**ex.** `Jan. 1 2013-to-Feb. 1 2014`, there will be a compounding value from `Jan-Dec 2013, "TOTAL=4,500,000" and Jan-Feb 2014, "TOTAL=45,000`".

What I have in the report is a continues compounding value,

**Jan-Dec 2013, "TOTAL=4,500,000" and Jan-Feb 2014, "TOTAL=4,545,000".**

My code in the cell is  `=RunningValue(Fields!DEBIT.Value,Sum,"summaryDataSet").`

I hope the reader would understand what I'm trying to say here and help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Though I don't know what kept you from using Google to find an answer to the question (by that I mean the question's header only!), you can use `ReportParameter` to pass parameters to your report:

```
ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[x+1];
parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("name1", value1);
...
parameters[x] = new ReportParameter("namex", valuex);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

I do not understand what you're trying to tell us by the question text, it does not seem to fit the question at all...