# C# 2015 winform datagrid view selected rows to rdlc report

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rdlc

I am novice to windows application and C#. I am using `C# 2015` for a `windows application` with `MS-Access 2007` database.

I have completed CRUD operations using form and display that records in a `datagridview`, seems working fine.

Now, what I want is display the selected `rows` of `gridview` into a report and print it. Also I don't want them to be display as a table but a form for each records. So that if 3 rows are selected then there will be 3 pages to be printed for each row.

The codes I have done are as below:

**customer.cs**

```
namespace bolt
{
    class customer
    {
        public int? id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string middleName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string panNo { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int dptype { get; set; }
        public string benificiaryId { get; set; }
        public string bankName { get; set; }
        public string bankBranch { get; set; }
        public string bankAccountNo { get; set; }

        customer(int? id = null, string firstName = null, string middleName = null, string lastName = null,
            string panNo = null, string email = null, string mobile = null, string address = null, int dptype = 1,
            string benificiaryId = null, string bankName = null, string bankBranch = null, string bankAccountNo = null
            )
        {
            this.id = null;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.middleName = middleName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.panNo = panNo;
            this.email = email;
            this.mobile = mobile;
            this.address = address;
            this.dptype = dptype;
            this.benificiaryId = benificiaryId;
            this.bankName = bankName;
            this.bankBranch = bankBranch;
            this.bankAccountNo = bankAccountNo;
        }

        public customer()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Added a form `frmReport` and `reportviewer` inside that.

Added a form `frmCustomer` which contains `datagridview`.

Added a `rdlc` report `rptBolt.rdlc`, I have not added any control inside it.

In `frmCustomer`, I have a print button. On clicking it the following code

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<customer> lstCustomer = new List<customer>();


    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgCustomers.SelectedRows)
    {
        customer c = new customer();
        c.id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[dgCustomers.Columns["Id"].Index].Value);

        lstCustomer.Add(c);
    }

    frmReport r = new frmReport();
    r.Show();
    ReportViewer v = r.Controls.Find("reportViewer1", true).FirstOrDefault() as ReportViewer;
    ReportDataSource dataset = new ReportDataSource("boltReport", lstCustomer);
    v.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "bolt.rptBolt.rdlc";
    v.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    v.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);
    v.LocalReport.Refresh();
    dataset.Value = lstCustomer;

    v.LocalReport.Refresh();

    this.Hide();
}
```

I have gone throw many tutorials but each of them are using report wizard and dataset that are directly connected to database, in my case I am using a list.

Let me know if am I on the wrong path or what should I do for it? You may provide answer or at least a link that I may get what I want.

Comment: The overall progress seems to be OK, what's the problem? Do you receive an exception?

Comment: In report viewer, it prints "some parameters or credentials are not specified". However, I am not sure how to map the list elements into rdlc fields?

Comment: So it's because you didn't passes *some parameters and credentials*. To map the list element, it's enough that they have the same name with fields of report. Read some notes about common problems [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40080499/3110834). specially tip number 2,3,4

Comment: Might be yes, I am not sure how to do it? Any link? Also, I don't have set any password for access file. I am just confused how to assign the "id" inside customer object of list to the report field?

Comment: Also to pass parameters: [Report Viewer .rdlc How to pass a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179801/report-viewer-rdlc-how-to-pass-a-parameter)

Comment: About credentials, I guess you don't need them for local report because you are passing list of data yoursef.

Comment: For above link, it is easy if you're using any textbox value, but in my case it is a collection. How to specify a collection element's property as a report parameter?

Comment: [How to pass multi value parameter to SSRS from asp.net c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002218/how-to-pass-multi-value-parameter-to-ssrs-from-asp-net-c)

Comment: The question is not useful in its current state, it doesn't contain a problem description or useful information about exceptions and so on. Also it contains multiple issues (which we talked about in comments), can you edit the question and make it more clear and include useful facts about problem?

Answer (score 1):

No need to all this code 
you just add a column in your aim table or in your select statement 
and assign a value to it for example `RSelected =1` 
just make update value to save Re selected to 1 and you have to assign after that to 0 or what ever value you need ,
then you can select this value in your code in SQL statement 
that's it ))))))

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass the result of the query written like "Select * From TableName" into a DataTable objetc to a ReportViewer?

You have to do something like this:

1. Create a new rdlc file that contain at least one Tablix object
2. Be sure the new rdlc file has Build Action Property set to 'Content' and Copy to Output Directory to 'Copy Always'
3. Create the method that receive the query

[See the method created here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oikcB.png)

4. Create the method to receive the DataTable object populated by the query

   ```
   /// Method that return a new Tablix formatted for our file Report_Dynamic.rdlc
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="datos">DataTable complete from Select statement</param>
   /// <returns>New Tablix with all columns and rows from your DataTable ☺</returns>
   private string CrearTablaDeReporteXML(DataTable datos)
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.AppendLine("<Tablix Name='Tablix1'>");
       #region TablixBody
       sb.AppendLine("  <TablixBody>");
       #region Tablixcolumns
       sb.AppendLine("    <TablixColumns>");
       for (int i = 0; i < datos.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
           //Columns
           sb.AppendLine("      <TablixColumn>");
           sb.AppendLine("        <Width>1.06in</Width>");
           sb.AppendLine("      </TablixColumn>");
       }
       sb.AppendLine("    </TablixColumns>");
       #endregion

       #region TablixRows
       sb.AppendLine("    <TablixRows>");
       #region Row header
       sb.AppendLine("<TablixRow>");
       sb.AppendLine("<Height>0.25in</Height>");
       sb.AppendLine("<TablixCells>");
       int numeroTexto = 1000;
       for (int i = 0; i < datos.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
           sb.AppendLine("<TablixCell>");
           sb.AppendLine("<CellContents>");
           sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<Textbox Name='Textbox{0}'><CanGrow>true</CanGrow><KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether><Paragraphs><Paragraph><TextRuns><TextRun><Value>{1}</Value><Style><FontSize>8pt</FontSize><FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight></Style></TextRun></TextRuns><Style/></Paragraph></Paragraphs><rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName><Style><Border><Color>LightGrey</Color><Style>Solid</Style></Border><BackgroundColor>LightGrey</BackgroundColor><PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft><PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight><PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop><PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom></Style></Textbox>", numeroTexto, datos.Columns[i]));                
           sb.AppendLine("</CellContents>");
           sb.AppendLine("</TablixCell>");
           numeroTexto++;
       }
       sb.AppendLine("</TablixCells>");
       sb.AppendLine("</TablixRow>");
       #endregion
       #endregion

       for (int i = 0; i < datos.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           //Rows
           sb.AppendLine("      <TablixRow>");
           sb.AppendLine("        <Height>0.25in</Height>");
           sb.AppendLine("        <TablixCells>");
           for (int j = 0; j < datos.Columns.Count; j++)
           {
               sb.AppendLine("          <TablixCell>");
               sb.AppendLine("            <CellContents>");
               sb.AppendLine(string.Format("              <Textbox Name='Textbox{0}'><CanGrow>true</CanGrow><KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether><Paragraphs><Paragraph><TextRuns><TextRun><Value>{1}</Value><Style><FontSize>8pt</FontSize></Style></TextRun></TextRuns><Style/></Paragraph></Paragraphs><rd:DefaultName>Textbox2</rd:DefaultName><Style><Border><Color>LightGrey</Color><Style>Solid</Style></Border><PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft><PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight><PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop><PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom></Style></Textbox>", numeroTexto, datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString().Replace("&", "")));
               sb.AppendLine("            </CellContents>");
               sb.AppendLine("          </TablixCell>");
               numeroTexto++;
           }
           sb.AppendLine("        </TablixCells>");
           sb.AppendLine("      </TablixRow>");                
       }
       sb.AppendLine("    </TablixRows>");
       sb.AppendLine("  </TablixBody>");
       #endregion

       sb.AppendLine("      <TablixColumnHierarchy>");
       sb.AppendLine("<TablixMembers>");
       for (int i = 0; i < datos.Columns.Count; i++)
           sb.AppendLine("<TablixMember />");
       sb.AppendLine("</TablixMembers>");
       sb.AppendLine("</TablixColumnHierarchy>");
       sb.AppendLine("      <TablixRowHierarchy>");
       sb.AppendLine("<TablixMembers>");
       sb.AppendLine("<TablixMember><KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup></TablixMember>");
       for (int i = 0; i < datos.Rows.Count; i++)
           sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<TablixMember />"));
       sb.AppendLine("</TablixMembers>");
       sb.AppendLine("</TablixRowHierarchy>");
       sb.AppendLine("      <Top>0.05556in</Top>");
       sb.AppendLine("      <Left>0.11458in</Left>");
       sb.AppendLine("      <Height>1.25in</Height>");
       sb.AppendLine(string.Format("      <Width>8in</Width>"));
       sb.AppendLine("      <Style>");
       sb.AppendLine("        <Border>");
       sb.AppendLine("          <Style>None</Style>");
       sb.AppendLine("        </Border>");
       sb.AppendLine("      </Style>");
       sb.AppendLine("      </Tablix>");
       return sb.ToString();
   }
   ```
5. Then you'll create the method that will read the old rdlc file and write the new one to be used for the ReportViewer Object.

This method looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Read the old rdlc file and write the new one to be used for ReportViewer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="datos">DataTable complete from Select statement</param>
    /// <param name="rutaActualRDLC">C\Reports\Template.rdlc</param>
    /// <param name="rutaNuevaRDLC">C\Reports\NewFile.rdlc</param>
    private void LecturaRDLCXML(DataTable datos, string rutaActualRDLC, string rutaNuevaRDLC)
    {
        //Read the report file into a XMLDocument
        XmlDocument documento = new XmlDocument();
        documento.Load(rutaActualRDLC);

        //Select the node 'ReportItems' that apear when you add a Tablix element empty
        XmlNode aNode = documento.DocumentElement.FirstChild.FirstChild;

        //Override that node with your DataTable, the same DataTable you passed to a DataGridView
        aNode.InnerXml = CrearTablaDeReporteXML(datos);
        //Save the new file written
        documento.Save(rutaNuevaRDLC);
    }
```

Finally, you have to call your report and pass the new path of report like this:

```
private void btn_print_report(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      //Remove the report dynamic that was create before
        string rutaNuevaRDLC = @"Reportes/rpt_dynamic_SQL_dinamico.rdlc";
        if (File.Exists(rutaNuevaRDLC))
            File.Delete(rutaNuevaRDLC);

      //Read the old and the new file
      //result is a DataTable type that contain the result of "Select * From Table"
        LecturaRDLCXML(result, @"Reportes/rpt_dynamic_SQL.rdlc", rutaNuevaRDLC);

      //Optional: if you have any other DataSources in your report
      //reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
      //reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSourceName", IEunumerableCollectionForThisDataSource));

      reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = rutaNuevaRDLC;
      reportViewer.Visible = true;
      reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
      reportViewer.RefreshReport();
}
```

I hope this post helps someone else ☺

Comment: Thanks for posting answer. I will check it and will let you know if any issue executing this codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        cmdSave.PerformClick();
        string sqlCmd = "Update tbl_Ledger " +
                        " Set RSelected=0";
        DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlCmd);

        string sqlCmd2 = "Update tbl_Ledger " +
                         " Set RSelected=1 " +
                         " where supplierid=" + this.txtSupplierID.Text + 
                         " AND  xRecDate BETWEEN '" + DateFrom.Text + "' AND    '" + DateTo.Text + "'";
        DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlCmd2);



        Ledger.LedgerRep go = new Ledger.LedgerRep();
        go.supplierID = this.txtSupplierID.Text;
        go.RSelected = "1";
        go.Show();
```